Is Marisa Tomei in the film the Toxic Avenger?
Listed in the credits of the film The Toxic Avenger (1984), actress Marisa Tomei supposedly was an extra in the film:

Little credit can be given to IMDb (when IMDb was in its infancy, anyone could edit anything on it based on a hunch), and she is indeed "uncredited" in the film.
When looking for a screenshot of her scene on search engines, an extra with very different physical features shows up in search results.

Several internet users have pointed out that the extra doesn't look anything like Marisa Tomei.


Additionally, according to the slide show located in the Special Features section of the Director's Cut DVD released in 1981 by Troma, Marisa Tomei briefly appears as an extra in the scene where Melvin runs away from the pool before jumping out of the window and falling into the toxic waste (hence not this scene).
However, IMDb lists producer Dolly Hall as "Girl in Health Club", who looks a lot more like the extra in question (hair color, hair part, eyelashes, eyebrows, facial shape, nose shape and eye color are a much better match).
There are also plenty of background extras with black hair that would more likely be her.

So there are a few possibilities:

Marisa Tomei was never in The Toxic Avenger, someone edited this entry mistakenly in IMDb many years ago and no one cared to fix it, the false information was then subsequently reshared overwhelmingly;

She was in a scene of the film, and the person who added this information is correct but her scene didn't make it to the final cut;

She is in the film, but the credit is wrong and she is in another scene where her     face is not clearly visible, and viewers who share this screenshot saying it is her     are mistaken;

This is Marisa Tomei and somehow her hair color, hair part, eyelashes, eyebrows, facial shape, nose shape and eye color looked different on that occasion.

This extra's name is Marisa Tomei, but not the Academy-Award winning actress Marisa Tomei.



"This is Marisa Tomei and somehow her hair color, hair part, eyelashes, eyebrows, facial shape, nose shape and eye color looked different on that occasion." Note this is completely possible because half of those are cosmetic and the other half change with age.

I'm not sure what you mean by hair colour not matching yet have no problem with the shot being of Dolly Hall...  The characters hair colour looks the same as Marisa's does in the 3 pictures you have side by side, whereas Dolly is obviously Blonde and therefore doesn't match hair colour in the slightest.

Maybe you're just not old enough to have seen her then and now... You'd know she looked like that.

For what it's worth I think it's fairly obvious that woman in the towel is not Marisa Tomei.

@JMac The difference between brown and black hair? Maybe you've never made this difference yourself but it's definitely a thing lol. People with brown hair can dye it blonde, yes. That doesn't mean that the extra and MT have the same hair color.

@MicroMachine I've seen plenty of shades of hair.  Both of those look like they could be the same, with any differences being from lighting (or even sun exposure making her hair color lighter).

Here's a much clearer picture of Marisa Tomei in 1984.. And a video. The woman in the towel is not the same person.

According to the film's (co-)director, Tomei was in the movie.

Q. One last question, if someone is new to Troma, how would you describe it to them and what films would you suggest they start with, to learn about Troma.
Lloyd Kaufman: That’s a very good question Phil. Troma is a 44-year-old independent movie studio. It’s the oldest movie studio in the world that is independent. People like Trey Parker and Matt Stone, James Gunn who did Guardians of the Galaxy (2014) after he did Tromeo and Juliet (1996) for Troma. Eli Roth, Samuel L Jackson, Kevin Costner’s first movie, I didn’t direct it, but it’s in our library. Vincent D’Onofrio, Marisa Tomei’s first movie was The Toxic Avenger (1984).
Interview: Lloyd Kaufman of Troma Entertainment

The official YouTube channel for Troma Entertainment has her scene on their list of videos and identifies her by name in a video called "Marisa Tomei in The Toxic Avenger (1984)"

Did you know that one of Marisa Tomei's first acting roles was in The Toxic Avenger as "Health Club Girl"!




You can also see the same actress running from the poolside earlier in the film. This would match nicely with the quote from the DVD, stating that she was also featured in this scene as an extra.




Him saying she is in the movie and there being a proof that her scene is in the final cut are two different things. I think the answer is incomplete until we have a proof that she is in the movie and where.

@MicroMachine - We have confirmation from the director that she was in the movie, and from Troma's official youtube channel that the actress depicted in the towel is indeed a young Marisa Tomei.

Are you also able to find a screenshot of Dolly Hall who is also credited as Girl in Health Club?

What additional "proof" would you require @MicroMachine?  Referenced quotes from the director is pretty conclusive in my eyes.

@iandotkelly A screenshot of someone that looks like her in the movie and isn't Dolly Hall would be a pretty god proof

So really your question isn't "is this Marissa Tomai" ... but "I am personally convinced this is not Marisa Tomai, can you help me prove this is Dolly Hall"

@iandotkelly if you prefer to think about it this way, ask yourself "Is Dolly Hall in the Toxic Avenger"?

@MicroMachine - You think that Troma have repeatedly and intentionally mislabeled this actress as Marisa Tomei? That seems unlikely.

@Valorum Is Dolly Hall also a "Girl in Health Club" in the film? if yes > show me a screenshot of her in the film. If no > then maybe the IMDb has mistakes? I could see a lot of reasons why Troma perpetuates a false screenshot. Obviously it gives them a story. Whoever manages their socials doesn't feel like telling them when they're asked to publish something wrong. Or maybe they don't notice.

@MicroMachine - Dolly Hall is probably one of the (ahem) sporty-looking young ladies seen working out in the club at the start of the film. There were a bunch of them. You should ask that as a separate question though, rather than trying to manage this through comments on what's clearly a strong answer.

@Valorum and are you certain Marisa Tomei isn't in the scene you describe? "According to the slide show located in the Special Features section of the Director's Cut DVD released in 1981, Marisa Tomei briefly appears as an extra in the scene where Melvin runs away from the pool before jumping out of the window and falling into the toxic waste." In other words, not this scene.

@MicroMachine - I think she's the girl in the small blue bikini; https://i.sstatic.net/E43kHypZ.png / https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTs4JzgRJ-c&t=109s. And I'm pretty sure that's still Marisa Tomei.

in the age of social media, can someone ask Marisa or Dolly, were the in the movie, which scene or what were they wearing?

@blobbymcblobby - Knock yourself out.

aha, I am too old for that technikkery boobab stuff, can you ask someone younger, more connected..?
